# how write XML for any website

Tags: objective-c

I am doing Objective C programming and I want send and receive requests(Login/data fetching) over the client/server.
Now the problem is Should I do it using XML or any other Method.
Also I know nothing how to write XML for any particular website.
I am hassling for many days.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML particularly SOAP is very bloated and the support in Objective-C is severely lacking. I would recommend JSON for lightweight use and in fact Apple use it for their Push Notification server.

If you DO want SOAP then check sudzc.com for an online objective-c generator from a WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such animal as "any particular website." Some return data in HTML, RSS, ATOM, or JSON format, others may use a custom XML schema all their own. Likewise with the data you send; they may expect requests via SOAP or HTTP, with any type and number of inputs the creators chose.

In short, you need to find out *exactly* what is expected by the one particular site with which you're trying to communicate, and give it what it wants. That's why programmers get paid the big bucks, because there's no easy "do what I mean" button. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is whether you should use xml or any other method of communication.

XML has been designed to standardize communication, which is especially handy for communicating between several parties, as the structure of the document can be formally written down in a document and can be validated, so there is no discussion afterwards about the syntax of the document.

Although that is a noble idea, XML is relatively complex and not as light weight as, for example, json.

As long as you are writing your own client that communicates to your own server, the protocol used between those 2 can be anything, and do not need to be XML.

Therefore I would suggest using a lightweight and easy to understand protocol.  Json is gaining popularity due to its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the output of the data on your server, I'd suggest you output the data directly as a plist. Plists are native dictionary objects that can be directly instantiated with `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsofURL:]`.

Take a look at the [PList programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) for proper formatting.